# Grouping points by location in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

I have surveyed points (sections). There will be 200 sections, each section 20-30 points. I want to create polylines (sections) out of the points. In order to do so, they have to be in right sequences (ordered from right to left or so) so program (ie. ETWizzard) would know how to connect the dots. Points in sections do have random IDs.

I want to write script, where logic is: assign points from .shp for each section to specific group (ie. S1, S2...). Then try to give names (sort) to points in section based on x,y.

Preferably, I want to do this in Python. I guess the most important question at this stage is: Is there a tool to select and group points based on the location/proximity or any one would hear about any similar solution? There has to be one, since sections are quite commonly used.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Before getting to the Python part, be sure to review whether the [Proximity Toolset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Proximity_toolset/000800000018000000/) and in particular the [Point Distance](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Point_Distance/00080000001r000000/), [Near](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Near/00080000001q000000/) and [Generate Near Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Generate_Near_Table/00080000001n000000/) tools, may be use to you.  The three tools mentioned currently require an ArcInfo license.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What I am looking for, is rather something like R partitioning/clustering. Thought, what I belive R tool for Arc do divide points only to 12 groups (at least thats what I could do with R installed on my machine). I do know there is Point Aggregation in Arc 10, which could be of use, thought for the time being I am forced to use 9.3.1.